# "Bus error: 10" when trying to set pandas column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is the code I'm executing trying to *rename pandas column by index*:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', dtype='unicode', delim_whitespace=True)
df.columns.values[2] = "id"
print(df)
```

I'm pretty sure this is not the best approach, but when I run this with Python 3.5 I get:

```
$ python3.5 test.py
Bus error: 10
```

This is the first time I see an error like this. There is no traceback, just this output string.

What does `Bus error: 10` mean?

---

Here is the `input.csv` contents:

```
visitIp        userId   idSite
128.227.50.161   a        35
24.222.206.154   a        35
10.12.0.1        a        35
10.12.0.1        a        35
10.12.0.1        a        35
24.222.206.154   a        35
```

(Using `pandas` 0.17.1)

Comment: Can you share the csv? (can you replicate on a smaller csv?)

Comment: For me it crashes without showing any error. I tried it with 0.18.0 and 0.18.1 (Python 3.5 Win10 64bit).

Comment: @AndyHayden the csv is there in the question at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a bit more idiomatic way of doing it: `df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[2]:'id'})`?

Comment: @MaxU I can do that, thanks for pointing that out. Still curious though, what is happening with that "bus error".

Comment: @alecxe, i can't reproduce your error using `pandas 0.18.1, Python 3.5.1 Win7 64-bit ` - it works properly for me...

Comment: @MaxU yeah, updating to the latest pandas helps. Though, I'm still interested in getting to know more about where is this error coming from. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, i couldn't find this error in the pandas / numpy source code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bus error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error) occurs when a processor can't access an invalid memory address.

`df.columns` is an instance if `Index` which is an immutable object in pandas. Any operation changing it, returns in fact a new object. Modifying its elements is illegal, for example `df.columns[2] = 'id'` would raise an exception.

You were accessing and modifying an underlying data of the index. Actually, not the data directly but a numpy `view` of the data, which could have been a temporary object. (Internally, `Index.values` is a property that returns `self._data.view(ndarray)`.)

I couldn't reproduce this behaviour either and I don't know exactly what happened and why it now works. It can very well be an undefined behaviour in numpy C/cython code.

Comment: I've reproduced the problem in pandas 0.17.1 and could not in 0.18. This is good enough to resolve the topic. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @alecxe I tried pandas 0.17.1 and 0.18.1, but both with numpy 1.11.0, and didn't get the error.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I can reliably reproduce it on Python3.5, numpy 1.11.1, pandas 0.17.1 on Mac OS X.

Comment: I think this issue is occurring b/c of a hardware issue not b/c of a module version issue