# Pandas DataFrame- Finding Index Value for a Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that has columns such as ID, Name, Specification, Time.

my file path to open them

```
mc = pd.read_csv("C:\\data.csv", sep = ",", header = 0, dtype = str)
```

When I checked my columns values, using

```
mc.coulumns.values
```

I found my ID had it with a weird character looked like this,

```
['/ufeffID', 'Name', 'Specification', 'Time']
```

After this I assigned that columns with ID like this,

```
 mc.columns.values[0] = "ID"
```

When I checked this using

```
mc.columns.values
```

I got my result as,

```
Array(['ID', 'Name', 'Specification', 'Time'])
```

Then, I checked with,

```
"ID" in mc.columns.values
```

it gave me `"True"`

Then I tried,

```
mc["ID"]
```

I got an error stating like this,

```
keyError 'ID'.
```

I want to get the values of ID column and get rid of that weird characters in front of ID column? Is there any way to solve that? Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try passing `encoding=utf-16'` like I suggested, additionally you can confirm what the real column names are by printing them using `mc.columns.tolist()`

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38316355/2285236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's utf-16 BOM, pass `encoding='utf-16'` to `read_csv` see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding

```
mc = pd.read_csv("C:\\data.csv", sep=",", header=0, dtype=str, encoding='utf-16')
```

the above should work `FE FF` is the BOM for utf-16 Big endian to be specific

Also you should use `rename` rather than try to overwrite the np array value:

```
mc.rename(columns={mc.columns[0]: "ID"}, inplace=True)
```

should work correctly